# How to prevent Linux from setting the TCP MSS header option?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp, ip

I find plenty of information on how to add / change the TCP MSS header option, but I can't seem to find how (if it is even possible) you can *prevent* Linux from sending the MSS header option in SYN-flagged TCP packets - it's just always there, no matter what I do! The RFC does not require it. I know some Windows hosts don't necessarily send it.

There is lots of stuff, also mss-related, under /proc/sys/, but - seemingly - not what I'm looking for (only options to change its value).

Comment: There's no setting to turn it off.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Comment: So it is. I need this information for a system test. To support my programming.